# 1 Edit Data of a PowerPoint Graph in Node JS & 2 Recommended File Storage

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, heroku, powerpoint, file-storage

1. I'm trying to figure out what pieces would work best to accomplish this (please see title and image). Recommendations? E.g. run a VBA script within Node JS? Or a C# program with [Edge](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) package? And taking into account #2?
2. My project is in Node JS and on Heroku (where they aren't too keen on having files) so will I be able to accomplish with the .ppt living on Amazon S3 or other recommendation?

[image: Edit PPT Data]

Comment: Should I be doing something differently to get help here?

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to go in another direction at the moment to meet deadline.  Posting my research should it help another.

Options explored -

1. Node packages [officegen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/officegen) or [nodejs-pptx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-pptx).  Neither allow you to edit an existing presentation's chart data.
2. NuGet Packages [Syncfusion](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Presentation.AspNet/), [Aspose](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Slides.NET/), and [Spire](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spire.Presentation/). Spire is the only one with a free option (up to 10 slides).
3. [Edge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/edge) / [Edge-JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/edge-js) - Edge-JS recommended given support for latest versions of Node.

Probably your best bet is to go with Edge-JS and build in Spire references in the C# portion of your code.

Outstanding question and a couple thoughts -

1. Still don't know that it would work on Heroku given file storage, e.g. would you be able to open a remote file from say Amazon S3 in Spire?
2. Def an interoperability uphill battle here. Has me thinking if best to go with an ASP.NET app on Azure.
3. Just wish the officegen and nodejs-pptx devs would get goin' on this already! :)